# Triggering a command with a command target

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, material-design

*I'm using Material Design though this shouldn't be relative to the question

```
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView>
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Sofar I've gotten it to trigger the command on double click, although I want to also set a command target property like:

```
  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=addhost}"
```

Comment: I'm trying to open a Material Design dialog when you double click on an item within the list. Though in order to open a specific dialoghost you need to have a command targeting the element.

Comment: *this would work if I were to put a command and a command target property on a button. Although I need to get it on a doubleclick of an item within a list

Comment: *Solved this another way by using the IsOpen binding then setting it to true on a double click event (addhost.IsOpen = true)